# Convert string to array and perform foreach, codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter, foreach

I would like some help in converting a string to an array and performing foreach on the array data.

Currently in my view I echo my string  `<?php echo $p['tags']; ?>`

and this gives me the following data `news, latest`

I would like to do a foreach on this data so that I can wrap the values in `<a href=""></a>`

How is this done? What is the best method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explode them into an array:

```
<?php

$all_tags = explode( ',' , $p['tags'] );

foreach ( $all_tags as $one_tag ){
    echo '<a href="#">' . $one_tag . '</a>';
}
```

The explode() function splits the string using a delimiter (in this case the ',' comma) and each item is passed into the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking correctly. Is this what you want?

```
$var = 'news, lastest';
$tmp = explode(', ', $var);

$result = '<a href="#">'.implode('</a>, <a href="#">', $tmp).'</a>';

var_dump($result);
// string(42) "<a href="#">news</a>, <a href="#">lastest</a>"
```